# ruby のモジュール化について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rubyのモジュール化の問題を解いています。
エラー文がなかなか解決できず、解決策がわかる方がいれば、教えて頂きたいです。

ruby main.rbで実行したところ
下記のようなエラー表記となりました。

```
$ ruby main.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from main.rb:1:in `<main>'
        2: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        1: from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/home/ec2-user/environment/human.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Animal (NameError)
```

main.rb

```
require "./human"

# インスタンスの作成
tanaka = Human.new("田中太郎",25,"電車")
suzuki = Human.new("鈴木次郎",30,"野球")
sato   = Human.new("佐藤花子",20,"映画")

# メソッドを実行
tanaka.say
tanaka.think
suzuki.say
suzuki.think
sato.say
sato.think
```

human.rb

```
require "./thinkable"

class Human < Animal
    include Thinkable

    #オブジェクトで何の変数を使うか設定する
    attr_accessor :hobby

    #インスタンスの値を初期化する特別なメソッド
    def initialize(name,age,hobby)
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.hobby = hobby
    end

end
```

animal.rb

```
#クラスの定義
class Animal
#オブジェクトの変数
    attr_accessor :name, :age

#メソッド
def say
    puts "#{self.name}です。#{self.age}歳です。"
end 

end
=begin
   def initialize(name,age)
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
  end
=end

=begin
animal = Animal.new('田中太郎', 25)  
animal.say
=end
```

thinkable.rb

```
#クラスの定義
class Animal
#オブジェクトの変数
    attr_accessor :name, :age

#メソッド
def say
    puts "#{self.name}です。#{self.age}歳です。"
end 

end
```

Comment: `thinkable.rb` の内容を間違えていませんか?

Answer (score 1):

human.rbに`require "./animal"`が必要です。